# Powershell don't pass Verbosity level to called functions

Tags: debugging, powershell, scripting, verbosity

Consider the following script:

```
function a{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Write-Verbose "A VERBOSE"
    Write-Host "A NORMAL"
}

function b{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Verbose "B VERBOSE"
    Write-Host "B NORMAL"

    a
}

b -Verbose
```

If we invoke function 'b' with the verbose parameter switch specified, function 'a' (that is called in 'b') is also called with an implicit verbose parameter. Is there any way to avoid this? (In other words, call 'b' with the Verbose switch and 'a' without it).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to suppress the verbose output for `a` from outside function `b`, you can use the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable, starting with PowerShell v3.

```
function a{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Write-Verbose "A VERBOSE"
    Write-Host "A NORMAL"
}

function b{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Verbose "B VERBOSE"
    Write-Host "B NORMAL"

    a
}

$PSDefaultParameterValues['a:Verbose'] = $False
b -Verbose
```

For PowerShell v2, you would have to set verbose to `$False` when you call `a` from the `b` function.

```
function b{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Verbose "B VERBOSE"
    Write-Host "B NORMAL"

    a -Verbose:$false
}
```

Comment: Using PS v3 could get `$PSDefaultParameterValues['a:Verbose'] = $False` but found `a -Verbose:$false` method works fine.